# Can not access wordpress configured in Docker even though its status is running

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

Im following the instruction here to make a wordpress site in Docker:
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/

1.pull&run mysql image:
docker run --name wordpressdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -d mysql:5.7

2.pull&run wordpress image and link the mysql container to it:
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql  wordpress

**and i can see those two containers running:**
[image]

**and i can inspect the wordpress container and try to get the ip and port:**
[image]

***also, when I inspect the mysql container, i can not use the host/ip to login into mysql browser,***

[image]

********edit-add -p *****************

I run the wordpress container with -p

[image]

[image]

**************edit again********************

[image]

********************update**********************

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

***********finally i made it work*******************

**finally, i made it work, if i run the container with specific ip for example 127.0.0.1 in the -p command:**

```
 -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80
```

it wont work

**if i dont specify the ip, or use 0.0.0.0 as the ip, it will work:**

```
-p 0.0.0.0:8080:80
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see "`PortMapping:null`" in your `docker inspect`.

If you don't map any port to one of the host, you won't be able to access said ports.
See as an example "[Viewing our web application container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/#viewing-our-web-application-container)".

The documentation does include:

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 127.0.0.2:8080:80 -v "$PWD/":/var/www/html  wordpress
```

Note the `-p 127.0.0.2:8080:80` part.
As [GHETTO.CHiLD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2569951/ghetto-child) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222890/can-not-access-wordpress-configured-in-docker-even-though-its-status-is-running/32223042#comment52334168_32223042), the url to access the service would be using the ip of the docker machine `$(docker machine ip):8080`.

As the OP mention, using a broadcast mapping is easier:

`-p 8080:80` => `$(docker-machine ip):8080` works

Comment: Hi von, I just tried run wordpress container with -p but still not work, please check my update edit,thank you

Comment: @Qing try a more general mapping: `-p 8080:80`

Comment: @Qing once you map the container port like `-p 8080:80` you will want to access word press by going to the ip of the machine running docker, not the docker container ip.

Comment: sorry Im very new to this concept, how can I check my docker machine's ip? I tried run cmd like ifconfig, i found vboxnet , but after i used the ip:8080 it still does not work, please check my update, thank you

Comment: @Qing type typing `docker-machine ip dev` (as in https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/e054d06163d6559ee5417fc577ea14befbd456ff/docs/reference/ip.md and https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/73c548c1f96b4f1fa7a4416782b49e4dc20225b4/docs/get-started.md)

Comment: hi Vonc, I tried check my docker machine's ip, but it does not work either.....please check my latest update in the post..Thank you so much Vonc, appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Vonc, please check my update , i managed to get it work, but its something related to the ip.

Comment: @Qing I have edited my answer to include your conclusion for more visibility.